# Как получить файл?

Tags: android, файлы

Путь : `/res/raw/file.txt` . Выдает исключение `IOException`. Что делать?

```
String fileDir = "/res/raw/file.txt";
File f = new File(fileDir);
if (f.exists()==false) {
    try {
        new File(fileDir).createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "Получена первая награда!",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    LinearLayout toastContainer = (LinearLayout) toast.getView();
    ImageView RewardImage = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
    RewardImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.reward);
    toastContainer.addView(RewardImage, 0);
    toast.show();
}
```

Мой код не работает. Делаю систему достижений, т.е. при прохождении до определенного момента (я пытаюсь так сделать) создаётся файл и открывается достижение. Соответственно, в следующий раз оно не должно открыться. Но у меня два раза он прошел через `f.exists()==false` и два раза показал достижение. Что делать? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Все файлы приложения "вшиты" в приложение и не могут быть получены способом получения файлов из ОС, на которой запущено приложение. Для файлов в ресурсах надо использовать такие [способы](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15912883/3212712):

```
InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.taskslists5items);
String content = readTextFile(is);

public String readTextFile(InputStream inputStream) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    try {
        while ((len = inputStream.read(buf)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        outputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
    return outputStream.toString();
}
```